# Can I take 2 laptops with me when I emigrate to the Philippines from the UK

Tags: philippines

I am emigrating to the Philippines and want to bring both my laptops with me.
Can this be done.
And what do I say to customs if they ask me.
They are used Laptops

Comment: Welcome! This might be a better fit for our sister site [expatriates.se].

Answer (score 3):

Of course.

I regularly travel with two laptops; one work, one personal.

I've never been asked about why I have two. It's a reasonable number. If you had 5+ then maybe they'd ask questions as that seems odd. But 2 shouldn't be a concern at all.

Comment: Agree. I've entered through NAIA with 2 laptops and other consumer electronics and nobody asked me anything about them.